# Timestamp default value different than current_timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, default-value

I' m trying to add a timestamp column to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `timecreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `session` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then I try to execute this code to add another timestamp column with a different default value:

```
ADD COLUMN `timeexpiration` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AFTER `timecreated`,'

ADD COLUMN `timeexpiration` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AFTER `timecreated`'
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) AFTER `timecreated`,
```

but non of theese works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two timestamp columns with default values that use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, however you can use a trigger before insert:

```
ALTER TABLE task
ADD COLUMN `timeexpiration` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER task_timeexpiration_default BEFORE INSERT ON task FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`timeexpiration` = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;//
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL versions before 5.6.1 would not let two TIMESTAMP columns in the same table, unless as you rightly noted with out defaults and allowing null.

MySQL 5.6.+ allows two or more TIMESTAMP columns in a table.

Comment: 5.6.20 version (executed this SHOW VARIABLES like "version";)

Answer (score 1):

How Aman said, it is not possible to use two Timestamp in same table. You could use DATETIME instead. Try something like this,

```
ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN `timeexpiration` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL AFTER timecreated;
```

Maybe this help.

Hint: you have to remove , end of last field after PRIMARY KEY (`id`), .